# StringComparison, why "TH" not start with "T"

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string-comparison

I am using `StringComparison`, `"vi-VN"` culture; Why does comparing string `"TH"` or `"Th".StartsWith("T", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)` return `false`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Th` is a grapheme in Vietnamese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_alphabet#Consonants). It is a single unit of text, rather than two units of text as it would be in English. Thus, `Th` does not start with `T`, as it is it's own unique character.

You would need to use a culture which does distinguish between `Th` and the letters `T` and `h`. For example:

```
"Th".StartsWith("T", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: A tiny bit of background detail: In old and middle English, there was be a letter called [Thorn, (Þ, þ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)), which, in modern English, comes out like the 'th' in 'the'. For a while, it was usually written looking more like (Ƿ, ƿ), and early printers would substitute a (Y, y) - leading to 'ye', for 'the', which was, nonetheless pronounced 'the', because everyone knew from context that the y was really not a y, but a thorn. Here endeth the lesson.